Is there any way of getting the total list of users Im following on twitter via Twitter api developer portal for free?
Title is pretty descriptive.
Is there any way of getting the total list of users Im following on twitter via Twitter api developer portal for free?
Im trying this after setting up my project and app in the developer portal, but its not working either wit the Bearer Token (app only access) or with the v1 way of Context types.
import tweepy


consumer_key = "MyKey"
consumer_secret = "MySecret"
access_token = MyToken""
access_token_secret = "MyTokenSecret"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Get the list of users you are following
following = []
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_friends).items():
    following.append(user.screen_name)

# Print the list of users
print("You are following these users:")
for user in following:
    print(user)


403 Forbidden

453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level.
and app only v2 Bearer token seems to not working at all, not sure why:
bearer_token = "MyBearerToken"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

print(client.get_me().data.id)

TypeError: Consumer key must be string or bytes, not NoneType
